# Loading transparent-background image from canvas in WebGL

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, opengl-es, webgl

I have an interesting problem. I'm drawing text with a custom font to a canvas, then loading that canvas's image data into a GL texture. The problem is the transparency of the background. I can't get the GL texture to have the proper alpha. The background of it is black.

See here:

`http://24.2.20.166/`

(Stackoverflow won't let me post the link directly... sorry...)

Relevant code:

```
this.ctx.clearRect(0,0, this.textCanvas.width, this.textCanvas.height); 
this.ctx.fillText(textObj.text, this.textCanvas.width / 2, this.textCanvas.height / 2);

gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_PREMULTIPLY_ALPHA_WEBGL, false); 
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, canvas);
```

EDIT: I'm an idiot.

```
this.gl.enable (this.gl.BLEND);
this.gl.blendFunc(this.gl.SRC_ALPHA, this.gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Comment: please provide relevant code in a filtered-down test-case. A link doesn't help anybody - especially when you have that much code. Also a link becomes redundant (due to link-rot) to future users with the same or similar issue.

Comment: I'm not really sure what to post. Seeing the actual issue is probably the most helpful. Hmm, I'll see.

Basically, this line:
`gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, canvas);`

It should load the canvas with the alpha channel, right?